# Laravel SQL Server, Concat Result?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I would like to get an combined string with Laravel using DB:raw(). I am using a SQL Server 2012 in Backgroud, but i am unable to the the following string scheme.

**mm-yyyy (for example, 11-2016)**

Its working with:

```
DB::raw('CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(MM, invoices.invoice_date),100) + CONVERT(varchar(4),DATEPART(YY, invoices.invoice_date),100) AS invoice_month'),
```

to get 112016, but when ill try with:

```
DB::raw('CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(MM, invoices.invoice_date),100) + "-" + CONVERT(varchar(4),DATEPART(YY, invoices.invoice_date),100) AS invoice_month'),
```

ill get an fatal PDO Exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, but the double quotes around the dash doesn't look right. Try single quotes.

Comment: Ahh when ill use single quotes and escape them, its working fine: + \'-\' +

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of double quotes around the dash, try it with two single quotes around the dash:

```
DB::raw('CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(MM, invoices.invoice_date),100) + ''-'' + CONVERT(varchar(4),DATEPART(YY, invoices.invoice_date),100) AS invoice_month')
```

Comment: Doh! I should have refreshed my browser before posting. :-)